# Kendo UI Scheduler connection to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm currently developing a web app using the **open source Kendo UI Scheduler** with ASP.NET MVC Visual Studio 2012. But i'm experiencing some trouble while trying to connect my scheduler with a local database to store the bookings made by users of my application.

I've been looking for documentation to help me with this but I haven't been able to set this up entirely...

I followed instructions about this on: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/scheduler/ajax-editing

I've added the Entity Framework Data Model and necessary code in Models like TaskViewModel but the problem occurs in my Controllers.

```
    public ActionResult Tasks_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        using (var sampleDB = new SchedulerEntities())
        {


            IQueryable<TaskViewModel> tasks = sampleDB.Tasks.ToList().Select(task => new TaskViewModel()
            {
                TaskID = task.TaskID,
                Title = task.Title,
                //Specify the DateTimeKind to be UTC
                Start = Convert.ToDateTime(task.Start),
                End = Convert.ToDateTime(task.End),
                Description = task.Deschription,
            }).AsQueryable();

            return Json(tasks.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }


    }
```

I get an error on the DataSourceRequest: the type or namespace DataSourceRequest could not be found. But I can't find to narrow down which module I'm missing or what else I'm doing wrong...

Besides that I also get the following error *System.LinqIQueryable doest not contain a definition for ToDataSourceResult.* on the code:

`return Json(tasks.ToDataSourceResult(request));`

Anyone who can help me here or has an other/better solution to make a connection to a local database using the open source Kendo UI Scheduler?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the allow get behavior.

```
return Json(tasks.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem cause I'm using the open source version.

Comment: The .ToDataSourceResult is from an extension class found in of Kendo.Mvc.dll. I assume this means the mvc support in kendo is not included in the free version.

Comment: Yes, it's due to the open source version but this still can be accomplished using Javascript thats why I opened this new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541079/javascript-local-database-binding-of-the-kendo-ui-scheduler